# Why does the log always say "No Data Available" when the cube is built?

Tags: cube, kylin

In the `sample` case on the `Kylin` official website, when I was building `cube`, in the first step of the `Create Intermediate Flat Hive Table`, the log is always `No Data Available`, the status is always `running`.

The cube build has been executed for more than three hours.

I checked the hive database table `kylin_sales` and there is data in the table.

And I fount that the intermediate flat hive table `kylin_intermediate_kylin_sales_cube_402e3eaa_dfb2_7e3e_04f3_07248c04c10c`
 has been created successfully in the hive, but there is no data in its.

```
hive> show tables;
OK
...
kylin_intermediate_kylin_sales_cube_402e3eaa_dfb2_7e3e_04f3_07248c04c10c
kylin_sales
...
Time taken: 9.816 seconds, Fetched: 10000 row(s)

hive> select * from kylin_sales;
OK
...
8992    2012-04-17  ABIN    15687   0   13  95.5336 17  10000975    10000507    ADMIN   Shanghai
8993    2013-02-02  FP-non GTC  67698   0   13  85.7528 6   10000856    10004882    MODELER Hongkong
...
Time taken: 3.759 seconds, Fetched: 10000 row(s)
```

The deploy environment is as follows:

1. zookeeper-3.4.14
2. hadoop-3.2.0
3. hbase-1.4.9
4. apache-hive-2.3.4-bin
5. apache-kylin-2.6.1-bin-hbase1x
6. openssh5.3
7. jdk1.8.0_144

I deployed the cluster through docker and created 3 containers, one master, two slaves.

`Create Intermediate Flat Hive Table` step is running.

Comment: Has anyone encountered the same problem as me?

Answer (score 0):

`No Data Available` means this step's log has not been captured by Kylin. Usually only when the step is exited (success or failed), the log will be recorded, then you will see the data.

For this case, usually, it indicates the job was pending by Hive, due to many reasons. The simplest way is, watch Kylin's log, you will see the Hive CMD that Kylin executes, and then you can run it manually in console, then you will reproduce the problem. Please check if your Hive/Hadoop has enough resource (cpu, memory) to execute such a query.

Comment: You can find the CMD by quickly search "Create and distribute table, cmd:" in logs/kylin.log

Comment: Thank you for your reply! 

I searched "Create and distributed table, cmd:" in logs/kylin.log, but there is no error message in the log, and the table was successfully created.

In addition, I found that when I load table in the kylin page, I checked "Calculate column cardinality", but the cardinality of each column  of Hive table is empty.

Memory: 32G
CPU: 8 cores, 2.50GHz